# Need to 2350 users per second in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have a task to load test on application which needs to respond 2350 users per second. For that I have set us something like this in Jmeter:

I have added a Thread group. In that I have set:
Number of threads(users): 2350
Ramp-up period: 1 Second
Loop Count: 1

Will it solve my purpose to load test of application with 2350 users??

Comment: Are you sure you need 2350 user or you need to test 2350 request per second ? Like Dmitri T said you may have 2350 users log to your apps but that doesn't mean they are hammering the server all at the same time. On the other hand certain client call may be more than just one request on the server. Ex: I'm loading a game and when its login it's ask the server the list of my pending game, my list of friend and my profile at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It will. But only if response time for each virtual user will be equal 1 second.

There are 2 common load patterns, for implementing both you will need [Timers](https://blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers)

1. Actually it might be the case you don't need as much as 2350 thread to simulate 2350 users as real life users don't hammer the server non-stop, they need some time to think between requests. Besides page loading time also needs to be considered.

   Let's imagine you have 2350 users. Each user performs an action each 15 seconds. Page loading time is 5 seconds. So each user will be able to hit the server 3 times per minute. So 2350 users will produce 7050 requests in minute which stands for 117.5 requests per second only. If this is what you're looking for consider adding [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Uniform Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer)
2. If you need to simulate 2350 requests per second, not users, you need to handle it a little bit differently. There are 2 Timers which are designed to set exact "throughput" - a number of requests per time unit. They are:

   - [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
   - [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) - an advanced version of the Constant Throughput Timer, available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project.

     Remember that above timers can only **pause** the threads, they won't kick off new virtual users if you don't provide enough on Thread Group level so make sure you have at least as much as you try to simulate, or it's better to have 2x more in your virtual pocket just in case. Also check out [JMeter tuning tips from 9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) as JMeter default configuration isn't something you can use to create such a load.

Answer (score 0):

The setup you described just creates 2350 parallel users (2350 separate connections), but doesn't guarantee that every thread will be completed exactly in 1 second. Ramp-up period - how fast all threads will start to send requests. So, in the case you described Jmeter will do the following:

1. Create 2350 separate threads.
2. The difference between 1st and last thread start will be 1 second (approximately).
3. Every thread will be implemented only once (loop count).

For real scenarios when you need specific throughput for continuous period of time it's better to use Constant Throughput Timer. It controls the amount of requests sent by thread(s) and changes delay between requests when it's necessary to meet the value you defined. So, your real throughput doesn't really depend on the total amount of threads (users). Sometimes less users can send requests faster (depends on your application).

To control your throughput while running, just add Summary Report to your test plan.

Moreover, for this specific scenario (2350 users) it can be potentially difficult to generate so many requests in 1 second. In this case, you need to use distributed load with some Jmeter slaves and 1 master.